# simplemodal not displaying <div> content with ASP.NET and VB

Tags: jquery, asp.net, simplemodal

I am beyond my knowledge here.  It has to be something completely obvious that I am just missing.  I'm trying to use a jQuery SimpleModal to display a confirmation that a record was added to the database.

I've managed to figure out how to get the modal to display; however, only the background of the modal is displaying.  The content within the div is not actually displaying in the modal.  In fact, nothing is displaying in the modal.

Background:

I use a master page and the default ASP.NET css site settings.  I've disabled the sites css (as you'll see from the screenshot) and only using the css from simplemodal.  I can not for the life of me get it to show the content.

See this screenshot for what is appearing: [image: Result of SimpleModal]

Here is my aspx:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
        CodeFile="CreateDocType.aspx.vb" Inherits="Admin_CreateDocType" %>

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h3>Create New Document Type</h3>
    <div>

        <asp:Table ID="tblDocType" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text="Type/Name:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtType" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="Description:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="40"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAutoNumber" runat="server" Text="Auto Number:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAutoNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">N</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Y</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrefix" runat="server" Text="Prefix:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrefix" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSuffix" runat="server" Text="Suffix:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSuffix" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPRRequired" runat="server" Text="Periodic Review:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPRRequired" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">N</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Y</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPRInterval" runat="server" Text="Review Interval (months):"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPRInterval" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSend_LMS" runat="server" Text="Send to LMS:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSend_LMS" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">N</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Y</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLMSCatalog" runat="server" Text="LMS Catalog:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCatalog" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server" Text="Active:"></asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActive" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">N</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Y</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="submitButton" />
    </div>

            *<div id="basic-modal-content" >
            <h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3>
            <p>For this demo, SimpleModal is using this "hidden" data for its content. You can also populate the modal dialog with an AJAX response, standard HTML or DOM element(s).</p>
            <p>Examples:</p>
            <p><code>$('#basicModalContent').modal(); // jQuery object - this demo</code></p>
            <p><code>$.modal(document.getElementById('basicModalContent')); // DOM</code></p>

            <p><code>$.modal('&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;HTML&lt;/b&gt; elements&lt;/p&gt;'); // HTML</code></p>
            <p><code>$('&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;').load('page.html').modal(); // AJAX</code></p>


            <p><a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/'>More details...</a></p>
        </div>*

    <asp:Label ID="lblAddStatus" runat="server" Text="Set at Runtime" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDocType" runat="server" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Type/Name is Required!"
        ControlToValidate="txtType"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="rfvDocType_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server"
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="rfvDocType">
    </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDescription" runat="server" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Description is Required!"
        ControlToValidate="txtDescription"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="rfvDescription_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server"
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="rfvDescription">
    </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPrefix" runat="server" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Prefix is Required when using Auto Number!"
        ControlToValidate="txtPrefix"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="rfvPrefix_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server"
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="rfvPrefix">
    </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
</asp:Content>`
```

Here is the code behind:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Dim objDocType As New DocType

    With objDocType
        .Active = ddlActive.SelectedValue
        .AutoNumber = ddlAutoNumber.SelectedValue
        .Created = DateTime.Now()
        .Description = txtDescription.Text
        .LastModified = DateTime.Now()
        .LMS_Catalog = txtCatalog.Text
        .NextDocNumber = 1                                      'Set default of 1
        .PeriodicReview = ddlPRRequired.SelectedValue

        If ddlPRRequired.SelectedValue = "Y" Then
            .PeriodicReview_Interval = CInt(txtPRInterval.Text)
        Else
            .PeriodicReview_Interval = 0
        End If

        .Prefix = txtPrefix.Text
        .Send_To_LMS = ddlSend_LMS.SelectedValue
        .Suffix = txtSuffix.Text
        .Type = txtType.Text

    End With

    If DocDB.CreateNewDocumentType(objDocType) Then
        With lblAddStatus
            .Text = "Document Type Was Added Successfully"
            .Visible = True

        End With
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(String), "ShowSuccess", "$('#basicModalContent').modal();", True)
    Else
        With lblAddStatus
            .Text = "There was an error creating the Document Type"
            .Visible = True
        End With
    End If



End Sub
```

And the css:

```
    #basic-modal-content {display:none;}

/* Overlay */
#simplemodal-overlay {background-color:#000; cursor:wait;}

/* Container */
#simplemodal-container {height:360px; width:600px; color:#bbb; background-color:#333; border:4px solid #444; padding:12px;}
#simplemodal-container .simplemodal-data {padding:8px;}
#simplemodal-container code {background:#141414; border-left:3px solid #65B43D; color:#bbb; display:block; font-size:12px; margin-bottom:12px; padding:4px 6px 6px;}
#simplemodal-container a {color:#ddd;}
#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {background:url(../img/basic/x.png) no-repeat; width:25px; height:29px; display:inline; z-index:3200; position:absolute; top:-15px; right:-16px; cursor:pointer;}
#simplemodal-container h3 {color:#84b8d9;}
```

I have tried everything I possibly can to narrow this down without any luck.  Any ideas for what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.  Something completely stupid.  In using the tutorials it kept listing #basicModalContent as the selector when the Div had an id of basic-modal-content.

So in my RegisterStartupScript line:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(String), "ShowSuccess", "$('#basicModalContent').modal();", True)
```

the #basicModalContent is not correct.  The issue is the selector has to match the div id.  Changing the line to:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(String), "ShowSuccess", "$('#basic-modal-content').modal();", True)
```

makes it work.  I'm not sure how it's working in the demo because I copied it piece-by-piece and it doesn't work on my side.  I've had to have missed something.

Oh well - it's working.  Thanks for letting me put this up here and for looking at it!